# Laravel does not return view

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Currently I'm working on a Laravel project and I try to return a view in my controller. So far, so good.

But, when I really want to show the data from the view, nothing gots returned. It only shows a white screen.

So, what can be the problem? I don't know yet.

This is my current code

```
public function show(Domain $inputDomain)
    {
        $domainId = Domain::where('domain', $inputDomain->domain)->firstOrFail()->id;
        $scanId = Scan::where('domain_id', $domainId)->firstOrFail()->id;
        $result = Result::where('scan_id', $scanId)->firstOrFail();
        return view('detail');
    }
```

The last return does not work, it does not show the view.

Good to know:
 1. When I just dump (dd) true, it works and I see the true-message
 2. The view really exists and it contains data (I also tried to replace the blade template with some 'lorem ipsum' data, but also that did'nt show up)

When I just do a dd on the View::render (made an `$view` variable and did `dd($view->render()`) it shows me the HTML (in the DD screen), but when I return it, it is empty.

**Comments**

According to a comment I want to show the Route that I'm using

```
Route::get('{domain}', 'DomainController@scan');
```

According to a comment, I also want to show that I point to a file in the root of `views/`

[image: views]

How can I show the view to the visitor?

Also good to know, (forgot to mention)
This is my @scan function

```
public function scan(Domain $domain)
    {
        Dispatch(new ProcessScan($domain));
        $this->show($domain);
    }
```

Comment: Are you pointing to the folder where the blade file is located? So if it was in a folder called Details you'd have return view('Details.detail');

Comment: @BinaryDebug No, the file is located in the root of `views/` - and when the file did not exist on the location, I also should not be able to dd the HTML via render()

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: @KoenHollander can you share your blade.php and can u add screenshoots your folders path (may be this is a matter of attention)

Comment: Maybe you got a cache issue in Laravel:
    php artisan view:clear
[info on cache clear](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-clear-cache-from-route-view-config-and-all-cache-data-from-applicationexample.html)

Comment: @BinaryDebug Editted the question

Comment: @MuradShukurlu Editted the question

Comment: @NicoBleiler Thanks, but also did'nt work

Comment: @KoenHollander on your route your function is "scan" but you have add your show function to this post .Change Your route like this : Route::get('{domain}', 'DomainController@show');

Comment: @MuradShukurlu Forgot to mention how I use that function. Changed the question

Comment: @KoenHollander you can try "return $this->show($domain);" on scan function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem

I forgot to return the data in @scan

Changed the code to

```
public function scan(Domain $domain)
    {
        Dispatch(new ProcessScan($domain));
        return $this->show($domain); //Added return
    }
```

And it is working